PID of notepad.exe in taskmanager different from pi.dwProcessId
I'm new to C and am working with the Win32 API to create a process with CreateProcessW(). This is my first C program. It opens notepad.exe and outputs the process ID using dwProcessId. But the PID that is outputted is always different from the PID of the open notepad.exe process I see in Task Manager. Why is this?
C code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main (void){

    STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };

    if (!CreateProcessW(
        L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe",
        NULL, // Command line arguments
        NULL, // Process security attributes
        NULL, // Thread security attributes
        FALSE, // Handle inheritance
        0, // Creation flags
        NULL, // Environment block
        NULL, // Current directory
        &si, // Startup information
        &pi)) // Process information
    {
        printf("(-) failed to create process, error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Print PID
    printf("Process ID: %lu\n", pi.dwProcessId);

    Sleep(9000); // Wait for 5 seconds

    // Close process and thread handles
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

For example, the console output when run is "Process ID: 35692", but when searching for Notepad in Task Manager, the PID shown is 20736.
What am I doing wrong?

Are you on Windows 11?

Could be that you have another notepad open?

No notepad open, im on windows 11. Really weird that PID is different!

Voting to close as not reproducible.

"What am I doing wrong?" - nothing at all. Your code is fine. You are simply not taking into account that sometimes the process you are launching is not the same process that the user ends up seeing. Sometimes you are launching an intermediate loader that then starts the real app, in which case you would be reporting the loader's PID while Task Manager would be reporting the app's PID.

Is this behaviour specific to notepad?

Please don't tag c++ in c questions. If you look at the path of the executable in task manager i bet it's not "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"

Not specific, with all apps. If remy is correct, and its checking PID of the intermediate loader, how can i print multiple PIDs of every process that starts from my program? I am the only user on the system.. The youtuber i followed had his PID show same in terminal and taskmgr. Not sure whats wrong ;(

Also, when i search notepad in task manager, there is only one notepad.exe process, which must be the one i opened

You could try the same with some simple console application instead of the notepad

On Win11 you get the updated version of Notepad, launched by the legacy version.
Settings > Apps > App execution aliases > switch it off for Notepad.  PIDs will now agree.  If you don't like the way it looks then just turn it back on.

Use Sysinternals ProcessMonitor and disable logging of file, registry and network events sk that only process and thread events remain. Then you will see what princesses are getting crested and what did they have.

@jarvic1207 "how can i print multiple PIDs of every process that starts from my program? - use a Job Object. Create a Job, assign it an I/O Completion Port, then add the Notepad process to the Job. You will then get notified via the IOCP whenever a new child process is added to the Job. By default, a child process is automatically added to its parent's Job, if it has any.

@HansPassant That looks like an answer rather than a comment

I've found that if you open Notepad first and then create a notepad.exe process. The PID of the notepad.exe in taskmanager is the same as pi.dwProcessId.


This does not attempt to explain what the issue is.

Accoring to  Hans Passant's suggestion:
You could try to turn of app execution aliases for your account in Windows 11:
Settings -> Apps -> Advanced app settings -> App execution aliases

The PID of the notepad.exe in taskmanager is the same as pi.dwProcessId.


This does not attempt to explain what the issue is.
